# What part of this Linq query is invalid for nHibernate?

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a query that resembles the following that I get a NotSupportedException ("Specified method is not supported") for. However, if I execute it at the `Distinct()` and then perform the rest in memory, all is fine.

```
MySession.Query<Person>()
  .Where(person => person.StatusId == 1)
  .Select(person => person.Address)
  .Distinct()                     // .ToList() here fixes it.
  .OrderBy(address => address.Addr1)
  .ToList();
```

Am I doing something illegal for nHibernate's Linq Provider here? If so, any idea how to manipulate this such that I can still run this in a server-side execution-deferred way? Ultimately, my query (`Distinct()` and everything before that) is abstracted away from my code that performs the `OrderBy` and `ToList`.

I'm using:

- Fluent 1.3.0.733
- nHibernate 3.3.3.4001
- odp.net.x64(and86).112.3.0
- .NET 4.0 Full Framework
- VS2010

Comment: What is the type of columns? For example, you can not make DISTINCT on XML column

Comment: No XML, normal string, number, & dates. Nothing fancy at all.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with entity Address. No ideas...

Comment: In my DB, the entity equiv of `Address` here is really just a status with an `ID` (int) & `Description` (string). VERY simple data here.

Comment: Maybe you should replace OrderBy and Distinct
`...OrderBy(address => address.Addr1).Distinct()`

Comment: I can't do that. My DAL performs the `Distinct` while the consumer is choosing the ordering. I think I'm going to start investigating performing a `MySessionQuery<Address>` and using projection to filter by the `Person.StatusId` instead - perhaps that's the work-around here. I still think this query should work and am very confused about what rule I'm breaking. :-/

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/12/performing-order-by-on-distinct-on-linq.html) will help you

Comment: So what I take from that link is that you simply cannot order data after performing a distinct. Do you agree that is the conclusion to take from that link? That's quite frustrating! On a side note, the query by projection does work!

Comment: @Backs Go ahead and propose an answer and I'll accept it. I'm going to post another answer to suggest my alternative query to get around this problem to help others but your answer is ultimately the answer to my question. Thanks!!

Comment: @Backs - Don't forget to post your finding as an answer to this question. Once you do, I'll accept it so you get credit! :-)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think, it was an answer :)

Comment: It was. The invalid thing that I was doing was performing an orderby after a distinct. A work-around is also helpful, which is why I posted it, but the fundamental answer is that there is a limitation in the Linq-to-nHibernate provider and your link is what made that clear. So definitely an answer! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibirnate has limitations on using DISTINCT and ORDER BY, http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/12/performing-order-by-on-distinct-on-linq.html

Answer (score 0):

My work-around to the nHibernate limitation that @Backs pointed out was to avoid the `Distinct` call and to instead query by projection. Here is an alternative query:

```
MySession.Query<Address>
  .Where(addr =>
    MySession.Query<Person>()
    .Where(person => person.StatusId == 1)
    .Any(person => person.Address == addr));
```

*(At least, I think that's the equivalent query if I haven't made any typos transposing it from our real code.)*